# Why is variance an important factor when carrying out a student t-test to compare two sample data sets?

Tags: t-test

Homogeneity of variance is a condition of a student t-test. If both sample data sets need to have "equal" variances, then how does it provide any additional insight into how significant the difference of their means are?

Comment: Are you asking about *variance* as such, or specifically about its *homogeneity*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Equal vs. unequal variances.** Suppose variances are far from equal, sample sizes are also unequal,
the smaller sample has the larger variance, and finally that the population means are equal, so that we should not reject $H_0: \mu_1 = \mu_2.$
Then the pooled 2-sample t test will reject more than 5% of the time.

Here is one example of such bad behavior:

```
set.seed(12)
x1 = rnorm(10, 100, 30)
x2 = rnorm(40, 100, 5)
t.test(x1, x2, var.eq=T)$p.val
[1] 0.006122506
```

Furthermore, this is not just one 'unlucky' case. Here is a simulation
looking at 100,000 cases. The pooled 2-sample t-test falsely rejected
over 30% of the time. That's an enormous false discovery rate.

```
set.seed(2020)
pv = replicate(10^5, t.test(rnorm(10,100,30), 
                            rnorm(40,100,5), var.eq=T)$p.val)
mean(pv <= .05)
[1] 0.32639
```

If variances are equal then the pooled test works as it should, and
the significance level of a 5% level test really is 5%.

```
set.seed(2020)
pv = replicate(10^5, t.test(rnorm(10,100,15), 
                            rnorm(40,100,15), var.eq=T)$p.val)
mean(pv <= .05)
[1] 0.05048
```

However, in practice, variances are often unequal. Using a Welch 2-sample
t test (in R without the parameter `var.eq=T`) gives very nearly the proper rejection
probability. [With 100,000 iterations results are accurate to two decimal places.]

```
set.seed(2020)
pv = replicate(10^5, t.test(rnorm(10,100,30), 
                            rnorm(40,100,5))$p.val)
mean(pv <= .05) 
[1] 0.05207
```

**Difference in means compared to size of standard deviations.** When population means differ, it is important to take variance of the two
samples into account. In determining significance, the size of the difference between sample means
has to be judged relative the the variability of the samples.

In the example below the distance between the means (15) is large
enough compared to the standard deviation (10) of the populations, that 20 observations
in each sample is sufficient to detect the difference.

On the stripchart,
the sample means (red `X`s) seem relatively far apart. Most of sample 2 seems to lie above $\bar X_1$ and most sample 2 seems to lie below $\bar X_2.$ A t test
finds a significant difference between these sample means (P-value about 0.001).

```
set.seed(817)
x1 = rnorm(20, 100, 10); x2 = rnorm(20, 115, 10)
stripchart(list(x1, x2), ylim=c(.5,2.5), pch="|")
 points(c(mean(x1),mean(x2)), 1:2, pch="X", col="red")
t.test(x1,x2,var.eq=T)$p.val
[1] 0.0008686614
```

[image]

By contrast, when the difference in means (15) is small relative to
the population standard deviations (25), then no significant difference is found with 20 observations in each sample. The two
sample means seem close together in a 'sea' of variability.

```
set.seed(818)
x1 = rnorm(20, 100, 25); x2 = rnorm(20, 115, 25)
stripchart(list(x1, x2), ylim=c(.5,2.5), pch="|")
 points(c(mean(x1),mean(x2)), 1:2, pch="X", col="red")
t.test(x1,x2,var.eq=T)$p.val
[1] 0.1196462
```

[image]